# Create ranges (100-106, 107, 111-119) from rows of 100,101,102, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, gaps-and-islands

I have a table full of all zip codes in the US. 
As you probably know zip codes are not necessarily one after another, so for Michigan I have these zip codes (just a sample):

```
48001,48002,48003,48004,48005,48006,48007,48009,48012,48014,48015,48017
```

What I need to do is end up with a single row such as:

```
48001-48007,48009,48012,48014-48015,48017
```

You can see that I am consolidating zip codes that are sequential into start-end range and if a zip code isn't in a sequence it would just be by itself.

I will only be working with a subset of zip codes, I am not doing the entire USA. So assume that I have a temp table with the zip codes that I want to work with, I can populate this temp table as needed. Right now this temp table has a single field for the zip code, but it can be defined however it needs to be.

I can use temp tables, cursors, or anything else, it will be done in a stored procedure. In case you are wondering why, we have sales reps and each are in charge of specific zip codes and we need to print out certain reps. When customer service gets a call from a customer they can quickly look at a printed sheet and scan to see the sales rep who would be in charge of that zip.

So the printed paper would look like:

```
Jim Smith...........48001-48007,48009,48012,48014-48015,48017
Heather Jones...59014, 59017, 59018-59022  (completely fake numbers, just as an example)
```

I realize that paper is outdated and we can use a website or any other number of methods to accomplish this, but for whatever reason it has to be printed so I am trying to condense the zip codes as much as possible for printing purposes.

Comment: When you say SQL 2014, do you mean Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Your title is a little confusing because most people would probably create a single range 100-107 rather than 100-106, 107 when constructing sequential ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following.

```
create table zipcodes(zcode int);

insert into zipcodes
 select *
   from (values(48001),(48002),(48003),(48004),(48005),(48006),(48007),(48009),(48012),(48014),(48015),(48017))t(x);


select case when count(*) >1 then 
             concat(min(zcode),'-',max(zcode)) 
            else concat(max(zcode),'')
        end as concat_zcodes
from (
        select zcode
               ,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by zcode asc)  as rnk
               ,zcode - ROW_NUMBER() over(order by zcode asc) as grp
          from zipcodes
     )x
group by x.grp
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

You want to group together adjacent zips of the same customer. I would address this as a gaps and islands problem, using `lag()` and cumulative `sum()` to defined the groups:

```
select 
    customer_id,
    case when min(zip) = max(zip) 
        then concat(min(zip), '')
        else concat(min(zip),  '-', max(zip))
    end zip_range
from (
    select 
        customer_id,
        zip,
        sum(case when zip = lag_zip + 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by customer_id order by zip) grp
    from (
        select
            customer_id,
            zip,
            lag(zip) over(partition by customer_id order by zip) lag_zip
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by customer_id, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ac5a2f8571f316dcabee8c1a5e86a705)**:

```
customer_id | zip_range  
----------: | :----------
          1 | 48001-48007
          1 | 48009      
          1 | 48012      
          1 | 48014-48015
          1 | 48017
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column with state and zip code, then this is a gap-and-islands problem.  For the individual ranges:

```
select state,
       (case when min(zip_code) = max(zip_code)
             then min(zip_code)
             else concat(min(zip_code), '-', max(zip_code)
        end) as zips
from (select t.*,
             convert(int, zip_code) - row_number() over (partition by state order by zip_code) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by state, grp;
```

For your final result, aggregate again:

```
select state, string_agg(zip_code, ',') 
from (select state,
             (case when min(zip_code) = max(zip_code)
                   then min(zip_code)
                   else concat(min(zip_code), '-', max(zip_code)
              end) as zips
      from (select t.*,
                   convert(int, zip_code) - row_number() over (partition by state order by zip_code) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      group by state, grp
     ) sg
group by state;
```

In older versions, you'll need to use the XML hack for the final aggregation.